# Показывать всплывающий блок после прокрутки

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Есть скрипт, который показывает всплывающий блок, если пользователь докрутил страницу вниз до определенной точки.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > 1800)
        $('#sbox').animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);
        else
        $('#sbox').stop(true).animate({'bottom':'-60px'},500);   
    });
    $('#sbox .close').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();  
    });
});
```

Все работает, но если пользователь опять прокрутит страницу вверх, то блок снова исчезнет. Как сделать, чтобы если он появился, то уже не исчезал независимо от прокрутки? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сорри туплю, просто удалить то, что после else